# How do I know if a URL is a valid/working Python Package Index?

Tags: python, pypi

How do I know if a URL is a valid/working Python Package Index (PyPI)?

For example, in the NVIDIA documentation, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com is stated to be a private package index. This is also implied by [nvidia-pyindex](https://pypi.org/project/nvidia-pyindex/).

Visiting this yields a **404 Not Found** error. I'm trying to debug other issues (e.g. Poetry). It would be very helpful to confirm that a URL is a valid Python Package Index. I want to know if the URL is dead now, or understand why it returns a 404 even when it works - this has happened to be with previous private PyPI's.